# dispatch_get_main_queue isn't working right in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, firebase

I know there are questions like this, but it just isn't working the way that I had it in `Swift 2`.  I was hoping someone could clarify so I can get this working the way it used to!  I had this code in `Swift 2` and it would detect a change in `firebase`, update the data in the table, then reload only the index that changed:

```
DataService.ds.REF_USERS.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock :{
       (snapshot) in
       if initialUserLoad == false {
           for (index,user) in self.usersArray.enumerate() {
               if user.objectForKey("uId") as! String == snapshot.key {
                   self.usersArray[index] = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){[unowned self] in
                       self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)])
                   }
               }
           }
       }
})
```

The `Swift 3` code auto-update changed it to this:

```
DataService.ds.REF_USERS.observe(.childChanged, with :{
       (snapshot) in
       if initialUserLoad == false {
           for (index,user) in self.usersArray.enumerated() {
               if user.object(forKey: "uId") as! String == snapshot.key {
                   self.usersArray[index] = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                   DispatchQueue.main.async{[unowned self] in
                       self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)])
                   }
               }
           }
       }
})
```

The error I am getting now is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 4 from section 0 which only contains 3 items before the update'

So there seems to be a thread problem.  Anyone know how I can make it work as before?  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: This is not a thread problem. It's clearly given in error that,"reason: 'attempt to delete item 4 from section 0 which only contains 3 items before the update". You are trying to delete an item at index which is grater than the total item in that section.

Comment: Have you checked the stack trace?  Which line does it crash on?  Set an exception breakpoint

Comment: It crashes when trying to reload the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not any thread problem, it is related to your data source. Your data source is not updated accordingly . You should check your data source before reloading `UICollectionView` since you are not reloading `UICollectionView` just **reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:** and due to the mismatch of data item count, it happens.